# Displaying comments on pages distinguished by GET IDs

Tags: comments, pages

Wordpress - comments_template().

I am currently trying to work with an outdated wordpress addon and I wish to add the functionality to allow commenting on certain pages.

However each page url looks like:

```
/match/?match=1
/match/?match=2
/match/?match=3
```

So when I post comments on a page they are displayed okay, however when a comment is made it appears in the 3 pages listed above rather just the one page the comment was made on.

So my question is how do I make it so comments_template() sees match=1,2,3, etc as individual pages rather than the same page with just different get statements.

*edit*

The URL structure is:

```
http://pantheones.com.au/pes-csgo-open-league/match-table/?match=1
http://pantheones.com.au/pes-csgo-open-league/match-table/?match=2
http://pantheones.com.au/pes-csgo-open-league/match-table/?match=3
```

Each URL displays different information depending on the number of match and I want separate comments on each match.

Comment: Please provide some details what that URL structure means and how is it implemented.

Comment: Updated a little bit, is that what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 2):

As far as WordPress is concerned, the individual match pages *are* the same page, the presence of your GET var is meaningless to WordPress.

option 1 - make the individual matches unique objects, such as additional pages or a custom post type.

option 2 - hook [`comment_post`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/comment_post?version=3.3&file=wp-includes/comment.php) and [`update_comment_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_comment_meta) when a comment is submitted to store the associated match id the comment was entered on as meta data. you'd then filter comment output in your [`wp_list_comments` callback](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments#Comments_Only_With_A_Custom_Comment_Display) to only display comments with meta value that matches the current match.